# Query with MS Access (Sort of BOM explorer)

Tags: ms-access

in a database I have a main table with parts and related quantities in warehouse, and many little tables with parts and related quantities to mount the device (that is the single table name).
I wish to build a query that asks for the device name and gives me the codes and the quantities stocked in warehouse (and maybe a column with the difference between the requested qty and the available one in warehouse):
[image]

Do you think it's possible?

Comment: I expect it is but your question is too broad, shows no attempt to solve issue, there is no code to analyze. Attempt code/queries and when you have specific issue ask question. Maybe a query alone will not resolve. Perhaps need VBA or build a report/subreport.

Comment: I don't have this kind of knowledge, only basics of Access. Can you suggest me a path to learn?

Comment: Google for tutorials on Access database VBA programming. IMO, manufactoring/assembly type database is one of hardest to build (family tree type is another). It is a common topic in many forums. Search and will probably find sample dbs posted in threads.